# Generating public/private key pair with limitations on the form of valid keys

Tags: cryptography, public-key-encryption, encryption-asymmetric

I need a way to create public/private key pairs with a special pattern for valid pairs, like for example all valid pairs must start with 3, only much more sophisticated than this example. I'm doing this in order to make it hard for another party to generate valid pairs.

**edit** 
I'm trying to use anonymous authentication where users are able to self-generate public/private key pairs based on an initial key. the public key is also used as a pseudonym for the connection to a server. I'm working on a location privacy protocol where I have to authenticate users but they have to remain anonymous. here there is a problem that pseudonyms change often so I can't prevent a dos attack so I thought of this solution to prevent it

Comment: Smells like security through obscurity. Why do you want to make key generation hard?

Comment: to make dos attack harder. if someone unaware of the pattern tried to generate valid pairs by generating all possible combinations this will make creating valid pairs slower. I'm using the public keys as pseudonyms in my system (in addition to their normal use)

Comment: I'm not sure if I get how this relates to DOS attacks (I probably miss something about whatever you're building), but the phrasing "if someone unaware of the pattern tried" still makes me think of security through obscurity. Assume everyone knows every detail of your algorithms, it's the safer assumption.

Comment: @delan please look at the edit. does it suffice?

Comment: @AlirezaKazeminia It will never suffice here, but it might on crypto.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about cryptography in general. It would be very nice if cryptography/encryption tagged questions could be transferred to crypto.stackexchange.com and security.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most asymmetric key generation algorithms will go through many attempts to generate valid keys, often because certain keys are considered weak because they fail predefined tests. In your case, you would simply want an additional test to check if they match your special criteria before being considered valid keys.

Programmatically, if you are using a third-party key generation library, you would have to keep calling the generator until it gave you a pair that met your criteria. If you wrote the generator yourself, it would save some effort to be able to just stick in your criteria as part of the algorithm.

In any case, I agree with the other commentators that this may not be a great idea. If you are requiring a certain part of your key to match a predetermined pattern, you are sacrificing some of your security for something that could easily be uncovered and abused by an unfriendly party.

I'm curious how using a public key as a pseudonym offers anonymity. The key is still associated with a specific private key that is associated with a specific client. It sounds like you're trying to filter based on the key/pseudonym, but perhaps that isn't the best idea. Would encrypted signing help?

Comment: the pair is self generated so the pair cannot be traced back to the client. I just want to prevent a malicious user from being able to generate keys fast i.e. I'm trying to make key generation using brute force time consuming.

Comment: Key generation using brute force is already designed to be quite time consuming if you simply use large enough key sizes. For asymmetric key generation such as RSA, 1024 bits is probably good. Use 2048 if you really want to be sure.